# Wrong $#argv of csh running in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, csh

It is running inside Jenkins

It is not doing what I expected because there is no args pass to `.login`

Inside `.login`, `$#argv` is 0 which I expect 1 (abc)

```
[] $ /bin/csh -ex /tmp/jenkins2437001351435617067.sh
source .login abc
if ( 0 == 0 ) then
echo Please specify a project name
Please specify a project name
echo source .login <proj>
source .login <proj>
exit
Finished: SUCCESS
```

This is the code in .login

```
if ($#argv == 0) then
  echo "Please specify a project name"
  echo "source .login <proj>"
  exit
endif
```

Jenkins create that /tmp/jenkins2437001351435617067.sh

which has "source .login abc"

Thanks

Comment: What is `/tmp/jenkins2437001351435617067.sh`? And why is a csh script named with a `.sh` suffix? I'd expect `$#argv` to be 0 in `/tmp/jenkins2437001351435617067.sh`, 1 in `.login`. We can't tell which of those is producing the `if ( 0 == 0 )` message.

Comment: @keith-thompson, Jenkins writes the contents shell step to /tmp/###.sh on the remote node, then executes that script

Comment: @barry1628, Csh programming is generally not a good idea - see [prologue of Ggrymoire](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html), [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html).